# GCD of three numbers (without using array) euclidean algorithm

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I have a task, that gives me a little headache here. The goal is to find Greatest Common Divisor with three integers, I succeded in doing it with two fairly easily, but with three it get's a little complicated when I can't use any arrays.

Here is the full code I used, finding gcd from two integers, tests all green:

```
public static int GetGcdByEuclidean(int a, int b)
        {
            if (a == 0 && b == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(null);
            }
            else if (a == int.MinValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(a));
            }
            else if (b == int.MinValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(b));
            }
            else
            {
                int abs1 = Math.Abs(a);
                int abs2 = Math.Abs(b);
                a = abs1;
                b = abs2;

                while (a != 0 && b != 0)
                {
                    if (a > b)
                    {
                        a %= b;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        b %= a;
                    }
                }

                return a | b;
            }
        }
```

And now I used the same principle for the GCD by three, but used something I found on web: **gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(a, gcd(b, c)) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c) = gcd(gcd(a, c), b).**.

```
public static int GetGcdByEuclidean(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if ((a == 0 && b == 0) && c == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(null);
            }
            else if (a == int.MinValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(a));
            }
            else if (b == int.MinValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(b));
            }
            else if (c == int.MinValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(c));
            }
            else
            {
                int abs1 = Math.Abs(a);
                int abs2 = Math.Abs(b);
                int abs3 = Math.Abs(c);
                a = abs1;
                b = abs2;
                c = abs3;

                while (a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)
                {
                    if (a > b && a > c && b > c)
                    {
                        b %= c;
                        a %= b;
                        result = a;
                    }
                    else if (a > b && a > c && b < c)
                    {
                        c %= b;
                        a %= c;
                        result = a;
                    }
                    else if (b > a && b > c && a > c)
                    {
                        a %= c;
                        b %= a;
                        result = b;
                    }
                    else if (b > a && b > c && a < c)
                    {
                        c %= a;
                        b %= c;
                        result = b;
                    }
                    else if (c > a && c > b && a > b)
                    {
                        a %= b;
                        c %= a;
                        result = c;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        b %= a;
                        c %= b;
                        result = c;
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is more of a mathematics-based question than a pure programming one. Some answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93731/finding-the-gcd-of-three-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep your solution for 2 numbers and call it from the one for three numbers by using this formula: **gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(a, gcd(b, c))**

```cs
public static int GetGcdByEuclidean(int a, int b)
{
    // Your working solution for two numbers...
}

public static int GetGcdByEuclidean(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return GetGcdByEuclidean(a, GetGcdByEuclidean(b, c)); 
}
```

Note, in C# you can have several methods with the same name, as long as the parameter lists are different. The names of the parameters do not matter, only the number or types of the parameters must be different. This is called [overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading).

---

A solution with an arbitrary number of numbers (but at least two):

```cs
public static int GetGcdByEuclidean(int a, int b, params int[] other)
{
    int gcd = GetGcdByEuclidean(a, b);
    foreach (int x in other) {
        gcd = GetGcdByEuclidean(gcd, x);
    }
    return gcd; 
}
```

Comment: Wow! It really worked, I didn't expect this kind of solution. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if you can overload with an array, for example something like this:
        `public static int GetGcdByEuclidean(int a, int b, params int[] other)`
            `return GetGcdByEuclidean(a, GetGcdByEuclidean(b, other[]));`
can it be used like this also?

Comment: Yes, you can recursively call these methods. Make sure to reduce the number of arguments by one at every call, until only two are left. E.g. `gcd(a, gcd(b, other[0], copyOfOtherStartingAt2ndPosition))`.